# Can't do a PHP sum of some values that are in my mysql table, help me

Tags: php, mysql

```
$req = $conn->prepare('SELECT SUM(VoteValue) AS FinalScore FROM votes WHERE URL="TCeLkdTOWM"');

$req->execute();
$data = $req->fetch(); 
$total = $data['FinalScore'];
echo "Score is ".$total." <br>";
```

So I have theoretically that should theoricaly do a total of all values that are in the column VoteValue and that has TCeLkdTOWM in the column URL of my mysql table (See my Mysql Table below)

```
URL VoteIP  VoteValue 

TCeLkdTOWM  10.0.0.1    6 

TCeLkdTOWM  10.0.0.2    -1 

eoirjgo 10.0.0.8    450
```

It should do 6+(-1) in the background and I should get "Score is 5" on my page but

The thing is, it's not working, there is no error code, nothing I'm just getting "Score is" with nothing else

Comment: You’re not checking for any errors. Add that first. You’ll probably receive an SQL syntax error.

Comment: add `var_dump($data);` after `$data = $req->fetch(); `. What do you get?

Comment: SQL seems valid. Is this your exact code or a minimal version? If doing binding please add that to the question.

Comment: @user4035 I'm getting C:\wamp64\www\Voting\vote.php:73:boolean true

Comment: @user3783243, it's the full version

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen newbie question : how do I add it ? I checked my code with php syntax error checker, they are telling me that there is no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysqli_stmt->fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) doesn't return the results of your query. That simply isn't how this function works.

Either use (with [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php))

```
$req->execute();
$req->bind_result($finalScore);
if ($req->fetch()) {
    echo "Score is " . $finalScore;
}
```

or (with [`get_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php))

```
$req->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Score is " . $data['FinalScore'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks the second solution worked, do you know how to put a php variable instead of "TCeLk-dTOWM" in  "URL="TCeLk-dTOWM"');"

Comment: See the documentation of mysqli->prepare and in particular example #1 on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php